# How to navigate image source to another xaml? c# windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

i want to navigate `txtBox1.text` and `bg2.source` to another xaml at the same time

i try to use this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MultiGame), bg2.Source);
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MultiGame), txtBox1.text);
}
```

it doesnt work. I hope someone can help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

Of course this does not work. As you call the Navigate method multiple times the Page `MultiGame`is loaded 2 times with each one of the parameters.
Why don`t you pack the two variables in one object array, and pass this to the navigate method?
Like

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MultiGame),new object[] {bg2.Source, txtBox1.text});
```

In the MultiGame class you now have to watch to the PageNavigated event. The navigation data is now your array.

Comment: How can i use it in multigame.xaml.cs? when im using this code
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MultiGame), txtBox1.text);
the code i put in multigame.xaml.cs is e.Parameter.tostring();

Comment: @user3091014 Now e.Parameter presents the array you passed in.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that? e.Parameter...?

Comment: @user3091014 e.Parameter[0] for the source, and e.Parameter[1] for the text.